# My Android device with USB host does not recognize my WiFi Adapter dongle. Is there a way I can install a driver or do anything else?

Tags: wi-fi, compatibility, google-tv

I bought an [Android device](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/android-full-hd-1080p-media-player-w-usb-sd-hdmi-rj45-ports-black-2-x-aaa-102992) that doesn't come with WiFi but comes with USB hosts and, as stated in the site, supports Wifi dongles. But mine is not working.

I successfully plugged in a USB mouse, keyboard, hard-drive and a bluetooth dongle but specifically the WiFi dongle doesn't even turn on (the light doesn't turn on).

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find a WiFi dongle with a chipset the device supports. Each chipset requires different drivers, so you'll have to find one that's supported. There a [discussion thread](http://club.dealextreme.com/forums/Forums.dx/threadid.1017582) on the site you linked to about exactly this.

Comment: Thanks.. I didn't even know this site had a forum for each product. I already ordered a compatible dongle for $10